# Parallax effect scrolling for fixed timeline

Tags: css, html, parallax, timeline

I am trying to create a bootstrap timeline where parallax effect is applied to content only with timeline selected, contents moves with parallax effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything ? please provide your code here

Comment: yes , if you provide your code , I can easily understand task

Comment: Naila, Hari, Timeline reference http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 divs. First one will be your parallax picture, second - all your content. For an any id(for example parallax ) and give next

`#parallax {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    background-image: url('background-picture.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}`

you will get affect like this https://alexk89.github.io/Portfolio-page/

Comment: Can you be more explanatory. I have a hard time understanding what you're saying here.

Comment: in html file you need to create empty div     <div id="parallax"></div>     in css file you need past the code which I wrote above. After that, bellow ` <div id="parallax"></div> ` create new div where you will contain all your content.

Comment: @codeepic Want to create timeline something like http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/two-column-timeline-not-responsive but on load page only one timeline visible (Say first element) and on scroll next timelines should be visible (Parallax effect) where timeline will be static.